# How do I make a protected webpage/panel with Firebase authentication?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-authentication

I want to know if I can make a protected website which only people which are logged in via firebase authentication can access and use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You just need to check if a user is logged in on page load.

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    const uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // redirect to login
  }
});
```

If the user is not logged in, just redirect then. That was for user facing part. You should setup your security rules in such a way that only authenticated users can access your Firebase resources. I'm not totally sure which services you are using but let's take Firestore as an example:

```
match /collection/{docs=**} {
  allow read: if request.auth!= null;
}
```

This rules will allow only logged in users to read data from that collection. These were basic rules but you can write granular rules such a user specific content and much more.

Comment: Can this be exploited in any way?

Comment: @Psuedo frontend code maybe reverse engineered and users maybe able to the UI but not the data from firebase as long as your security rules are setup properly

Comment: Alright thanks, will try and set it up properly (sec rules)